# Преобразовать массив пикселей в изображение в ios

Tags: массивы, ios, objective-c, обработка-изображений

Доброго времени суток коллеги! У меня похоже не правильно работает [эта](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650144/how-to-convert-bytearray-to-image-in-objective-c) функция. Мне нужно:

1. Cоздать массив.
2. Установить массив в качестве изображения

Я написал примерно такую реализацию:

```
 //функция создаёт массив пикселей
- (void)ProccessImage { //352*288*4 = РАЗМЕР КАРТИНКИ

    unsigned char * buf = (unsigned char*)malloc(352*288*4);//выделить память под массив
    unsigned int *ibuf = (unsigned int *)buf; //

    for(int i = 0; i<352*288*4; i++){ //заполняем массив пикселей
        ibuf[i] = i|0x80808080;
    }
    UIImage*imageFromArray = [self convertBitmapRGBA8ToUIImage:buf withWidth:352 withHeight:288]; //создание изображения из массива пикселей.
    [ChangeImageView setImage:imageFromArray]; //установка  изображения в ImageView         

    free(buf);
}

/*Функция по конвертации массива unsigned сhar в картинку. Дёрнута отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650144/how-to-convert-bytearray-to-image-in-objective-c
*/
- (UIImage *) convertBitmapRGBA8ToUIImage:(unsigned char *) buffer
                                withWidth:(int) width
                               withHeight:(int) height {


    size_t bufferLength = width * height * 4;
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer, bufferLength, NULL);
    size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
    size_t bitsPerPixel = 32;
    size_t bytesPerRow = 4 * width;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    if(colorSpaceRef == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Error allocating color space");
        CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
        return nil;
    }

    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

    CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(width,
                                    height,
                                    bitsPerComponent,
                                    bitsPerPixel,
                                    bytesPerRow,
                                    colorSpaceRef,
                                    bitmapInfo,
                                    provider,   // data provider
                                    NULL,       // decode
                                    YES,            // should interpolate
                                    renderingIntent);

    uint32_t* pixels = (uint32_t*)malloc(bufferLength);

    if(pixels == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Error: Memory not allocated for bitmap");
        CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
        CGImageRelease(iref);
        return nil;
    }
  //  memcpy(pixels,buffer,bufferLength);
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels,
                                                 width,
                                                 height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent,
                                                 bytesPerRow,
                                                 colorSpaceRef,
                                                 bitmapInfo);

    if(context == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Error context not created");
        free(pixels);
    }

    UIImage *image = nil;
    if(context) {

        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height), iref);

        CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

        // Support both iPad 3.2 and iPhone 4 Retina displays with the correct scale
        if([UIImage respondsToSelector:@selector(imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:)]) {
            float scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
            image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
        } else {
            image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
        }

        CGImageRelease(imageRef);   
        CGContextRelease(context);  
    }

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGImageRelease(iref);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);

    if(pixels) {
        free(pixels);
    }   
    return image;
}
//Конец функции по конвертации массива в изображение
```

В результате вышеуказанной реализации, устанавливается в `imageView` белый экран.

**Вопрос:** Как изменить реализацию так, чтобы в `imageView` был заполнен разноцветными точками (чем-нибудь отличающимся от белого цвета)?

Comment: Попробуй предзаполнить пиксели `for (int i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {pixels[i] = rand() % 255;}`

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь - нужно вызвать `CGBitmapContextCreate`, потом сразу с него брать `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`. Битмап сосдастся по пикселям, их сразу можно в картинку вытащить. А ты между этими шагами ещё врисовываешь картинку, которая вполне возможно может оказаться белой. Ну очень понятно зачем тут эта картинка iref. Вот твой вопрос http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247927/creating-image-from-pixel-data-with-cgbitmapcontextcreate

Comment: @markov сейчас попробую. Но будет здорово если вы подробнее напишите код в качестве ответа, раз уже вникли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот этот код генерирует мне картинку шума, если его вставить, например, во `viewDidLoad`

```
int width = 500;
int height = 500;

size_t bufferLength = width * height * 4;
uint8_t* pixels = (uint8_t*)malloc(bufferLength);
for (int i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
    pixels[i] = rand() % 255;
}

CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, width, height, 8, width * 4, space, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

CGImageRef toCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
UIImage * uiimage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:toCGImage];

CGImageRelease(toCGImage);
CGColorSpaceRelease(space);
CGContextRelease(ctx);
free(pixels);
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:uiimage];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

**Для заполнения массива чем-то конкретным**

Есть формат пикселя, который определяется параметром `kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast`. Это значит `RGBA`, то есть каждый пиксель состоит из 4-х байтов, последовательно - красный (Red), зелёный (Green), синий (Blue), альфа (прозрачность). То есть, для установки конкретного массива пикселей, нужно забивать массив последовательностью из 4-х байт, последний из которых - 255 (то есть без прозрачности). 
Например:

```
for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++)
 {
  pixels[i * 4] = 100;       //баланс красного
  pixels[i * 4 + 1] = 200;  //баланс зеленого
  pixels[i * 4 + 2] = 50;  //баланс синего
  pixels[i * 4 +3] = 255; //прозрачности
 }
```

Comment: четвертая строка с конца выдаёт ошибку - `image` не используется больше.  Я её заменил на uiimage и ещё цикл for сделал `bufferLength/4` вместо `bufferLength`. И всё равно даёт только белый фон, как раньше.

Comment: Обновил код, теперь он точно генерирует шум. Нужно только разобраться с порядком каналов, который от тебя ожидает ось, он определяется параметром `kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast`

Comment: Обрати внимание - ещё я правил `uint32_t` -> `uint8_t`

Comment: то что нужно. Где и как Вы этому научились?

Comment: Опыт работы, в большинстве своём, и в частности недавно редактировал библиотеку, работающую с openGL, там из видеокарты доставалась текстура - тот же массив пикселей, потом перегонялись в `UIImage`, как раз этот метод и использовался. Если изучать iOS последовательно и главное с осознанием того, что делаешь - такие вещи будут простыми и понятными. Работа с `CGContext` не представляет сложности, если знать все функции и несколько подводных камней. Все функции - это не так уж и много, пробежавшись глазами по CGContext.h и CGBitmapContext.h можно вполне составить представление о возможностях.

Comment: уважаемый @markov, А почему если я в цикле `for` изменю `pixels[i] = rand() % 255;` на `pixels[i] = 135;` будет пустой белый фон, а не какой-то другой фон? Ведь по идее, изменяя номер, мы изменяем цвет каждого элемента массива пикселей. Можете пояснить, как в этом цикле установить единый цвет для пикселей? А то вообще не ясно.

Comment: Есть формат пикселя, который определяется вот этим параметром `kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast`. Это значит RGBA, то есть каждый пиксель состоит из 4-х байтов, последовательно - красный, зелёный, синий, альфа. То есть нужно забивать массив последовательностью из 4-х байт, последний из которых - 255 (то есть без прозрачности). Например `for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) { pixels[i * 4] = 100; pixels[i * 4 + 1] = 200; pixels[i * 4 + 2] = 50; pixels[i * 4 +3] = 255;}`