# Как нарисовать картинку на весь экран айфона с помощью openGL

Tags: objective-c, opengl, изображения

Уважаемые коллеги!
Требуется установить картинку на весь экран `ios`-фона c помощью `openGL`. Проблема в том, что просто устанавливать картинку на экран яблофона я умею, но как это сделать с помощью `openGL` - ума не приложу.

**Вопрос:** как нарисовать (установить) картинку на весь экран `ios` фона с помощью `openGL`? (Подбросьте примерчик рабочий на `Objective-c`, очень надо).

Comment: под экраном подразумевается экран приложения, так ведь? Если так, то чем не устраивает `UIImageView`?

Comment: UIImageView не устраивает тем, что обновление функций обработки изображений жрёт дофига памяти. Помните ваш [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/582140) по массиву пикселей? Так вот, при скорости камеры 30 кадров в секунду, сия функция понижает скорость кадров примерно в двое, что не приемлимо. Есит команда, попробовать на чём-нибудь более низкоуровневом написать, то что нужно.